# print XML tag with bash

Tags: xml, bash, search, printing

I am trying to figure out how to use bash to print a certain line in a few XML files.  These files are located in several folders.  The line I need to print is an exact XML tag called 
`<name></name>`.

My objectives:

- search through folders
- print folder location on one line
- print file name on second line
- print what is between

I only need the name and not the full path and I do need it to add to a .txt file called whatever.  Ive tried with bash but Im stuck on this one.

EDIT:
I also forgot to mention that this is a piece being added to some other shell script so Im unsure if I can get grep to work within it.

Comment: "stuck on this one" implies you have some code. Why not post it so we can help you fix your problem. Good luck.

Comment: I am completely stuck on trying to figure out how to echo within the XML tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using grep and a regular expression recursively on a directory shows you the file names (including the path) with the tag in it:

```
grep -r "<name>.*</name>" /path/to/directory
```

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with `XML`, the better approach is to use real tools like `xmllint` or `xmlstarlet`.

By example :

```
find /path -iname '*xml' -exec xmllint --xpath '//name/text()' {} +
```

That will do the trick recursively.

Comment: you mind explaining to me whats going on so I can understand what is being done??

Comment: `find` search all xml files in `/path` recursively, and for each files execute the `xmllint` command with a Xpath expression. `xmllint` command is packaged in `libxml`